# Textexpander add text to last line

Tags: text

I would like to add a new TextExpander snippet to do the following:

I will add a url from the clipboard in the form of:

> This is my text with a link [1] and one more link [2]
>
> [1] http//link1
>   [2] http//link2

I wrote this:

```
[%filltext:name=number:default=1%] %|
[%filltext:name=number:default=1%] %clipboard
```

But the problem is, I don't know how to add the 2nd link after the first.

I get this instead this:

> This is my text with a link [1] and one more link [2]
>
> [2] http//link2
>   [1] http//link1

How can I add text in the last line?

Comment: Even with the editing, I still don't understand what is being asked. It would be helpful to show what is supposed to be on the clipboard (I would guess one of the links, but it seems unlikely there could be two different links). I do notice that the two `%filltext%`s have the same name, so they will be forced to have the same value -- perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: Hi,sorry for this. the [1] and [2] came from two times adding :link.
First one I add "1" and second "2"
And the to times filltext is to add the same number in the text and at the bottom of the text. My question ist, how to add text on the last line of text. And it does no matter if there is text betweet.

Comment: I think I finally understand what it is you want. At step one you have `This is my text with a link [1]\r\r[1]link1` and then you want to type `and one more link`, then you want to end up with the text being as in your first example. Unfortunately I can't think of a good way to accomplish this with TextExpander. It does not know how to go down to the end of your document, possibly skipping over text like `[1]link1`, add `[2]link2` then get back up to where you were typing before.

Comment: @SmilinBrian If we need not "get back up to where you were typing before", is it possible?

Comment: It is possible but very complicated. You could have a snippet output a Markdown link, then launch a delayed-execution AppleScript app which could use `keystroke` commands to Command-Shift-Down-Arrow to get to the bottom of the text file, then `keystroke "["` etc plus key Command-V to Paste in the link.